# SQL modify and insert as new row in the original table

Tags: sql

I have a single table with single column, 
I want to modify rows in original table and insert them as new row.

```
originalTable - >| xyz  |
                 --------
                 | abc1 |
```

need a sql expert to refactor this query into a single sql query if possble, (here is want I have done,

1) here I create two separate temporary tables to do all the processing

2) and then join them to the original table,

I want to eliminate the creation of these tables, if I can perform all the below queries in a single statement)

```
create table #tmp1(
 xyz varchar(10)
)
create table #tmp2(
 xyz varchar(10)
)

insert into #tmp1 (xyz)
select xyz from originalTable

insert into #tmp2 (xyz)
select xyz from originalTable

update #tmp1(xyz)
select xyz = (SUBSTRING(xyz, 1, 8)) || 'P'

update #tmp2(xyz)
select xyz = (SUBSTRING(xyz, 1, 8)) || 'R'

insert into #originalTable (xyz)
select xyz from #tmp_1
UNION
select xyz from #tmp_2

originalTable - > | xyz  |
                  -------- 
                  | abc1 |
                  | abcP |
                  | abcR |
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL? MySQL doesn't use `#` for temporary tables, it uses `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`.

Comment: And it uses the `CONCAT` function for concatenation, not `||`. What RDBMS are you really using?

Answer (score 3):

Just write a query that returns all the substring concatenations, and use that as the source in an `INSERT` statement.

```
INSERT INTO originalTable (xyz)
SELECT (SUBSTRING(xyz, 1, 8)) || 'P'
FROM originalTable
UNION
SELECT (SUBSTRING(xyz, 1, 8)) || 'R'
FROM originalTable
```